# Simple Query Performance Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries that run back to back and fill two separate grids.  They don't run in the same instance of an sql query, but back to back no less.

I have ran these two queries in SSMS and it's about 5 seconds per query.  BO_HRO has ~600,000 rows and BO_HParts has ~1,200,000 rows with a one-to-many relationship respectively.  I also have an index as suggested by SSMS on BO_HRO of deleted_by, RO_NO, and BName as well as an index on BO_HParts of deleted_by, RO_NO, Quanity, PartNo, and PartDesc.

```
SELECT TOP 10000 bo_hparts.partno, 
                          bo_hparts.partdesc, 
                          SUM(bo_hparts.quanity) AS qtysum

FROM bo_hparts INNER JOIN bo_hro ON bo_hparts.ro_no = bo_hro.ro_no

WHERE bo_hparts.deleted_by < 0 AND bo_hro.deleted_by < 0

GROUP BY bo_hparts.partno, bo_hparts.partdesc
ORDER BY SUM(bo_hparts.quanity) DESC, bo_hparts.partno;

SELECT TOP 10000 bo_hro.bname, 
                          bo_hparts.partno, 
                          bo_hparts.partdesc, 
                          SUM(bo_hparts.quanity) AS qtysum

FROM bo_hparts INNER JOIN bo_hro ON bo_hparts.ro_no = bo_hro.ro_no

WHERE bo_hparts.deleted_by < 0 AND bo_hro.deleted_by < 0

GROUP BY bo_hro.bname, bo_hparts.partno, bo_hparts.partdesc
ORDER BY SUM(bo_hparts.quanity) DESC, bo_hro.bname, bo_hparts.partno
```

My boss is still asking for increased performance and I'm not sure what else to do to pull that off.  Is there any other way to boost the speed?

I have an execution plan here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99733863/BO_HParts%20Join%20BO_HRO.sqlplan

Comment: Please update the queries with table aliases so we can tell which tables the columns come from.  Also, you can remove the `distinct` -- see if that helps performance at all.  And, does `deleted_by` take on a single value (such as `-1`) or are you really checking for multiple values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added aliases and 'distinct' didn't make a difference.  Your deleted_by assumption is correct, it's just a single value of either -1 or 1 (-1 not deleted, 1 is deleted)

Comment: In that case, for starters you can simply use `= -1` in place of `< 0`.  I don't know how much impact this will have, but it's worth doing in any case...

Comment: `order by sum(...)` is bad. It means that the `top 10000` has to happen after summing all the rows - that's expensive. Rather than modifying the query, perhaps it would be better if you added the sum as a column to the parent table? It could have an index in that case, and rather than going through a million rows, you'd only be crawling ten thousand. Of course, updates would be more expensive, but that's why it's called a tradeoff.

Comment: @PinnyM ` = -1` didn't change performance.  I did take off the order by and that brought each query to 3 seconds each; however, this changes the intended results.

Comment: @Luaan I agree completely that this calculation shouldn't be done on the fly in this case, but we cannot modify the parent table and if we start adding extension tables things will get out of hand as I would be creating an entire separate table for one query.  Due to my environment restrictions I cannot make a temp table either.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a view for the aggregated - it should be possible to add an index even on aggregated columns of the view, and it should be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

Change the `where` clause to an explicit comparison:

```
WHERE bo_hparts.deleted_by = -1 AND bo_hro.deleted_by = -1
```

This will allow you to use composite indexes, such as `bo_hparts(deleted_by, ro_no)`.  That might help the query.

Create a covering index for `bo_hro`.  This would be `bo_hro(ro_no, deleted_by, quantity)`.  If the records are wide, this might help.

A covering index for `bo_hparts` might also help, but this is probably a smaller table, so it might not be as important.

If there is a minimum quantity that you care about, then try adding:

```
having sum(bo_hparts.quantity) > 1000
```

This could make the `order by` more efficient.

In the end, though, what you are trying to do is computationally intensive.  If you need real-time performance for this type of query, you might need to think about using a trigger to keep the summary data up-to-date.  This would reduce the query just to an `order by` -- which you could even optimize by having an index in the summary data.

Comment: While I can't really put any of these into place except the explicit comparison they would all help.  My boss is reluctant to index the table just for this query and keeping a trigger would be overkill for what he wants.  It sucks having to tell your boss this isn't going to work without extra pieces put into place, but that's what it comes down to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change your group by clause, so use table aliases/names?

Comment: Table names had no effect.

Comment: Let me try to rewrite that:

SELECT TOP 10000 bo_hparts.partno, 
                          bo_hparts.partdesc, 
                          SUM(bo_hparts.quanity) AS qtysum

FROM bo_hparts a, bo_hro b

WHERE a.ro_no = b.ro_no
AND bo_hparts.deleted_by < 0 
AND bo_hro.deleted_by < 0

GROUP BY bo_hparts.partno, bo_hparts.partdesc
ORDER BY SUM(bo_hparts.quanity) DESC, bo_hparts.partno;

Comment: @Laurens You should add that information into your answer, not as a comment.